# CSS width calc is not working in mobile UC browser?

Tags: css, cross-browser

here is my code:
`

```
.column1{
 width:calc(100% - 100px);
float:left;
}
.column2{
width:100px;
float:left;
}
```

`

The above code is not working in mobile UC Browser.

Is there any specific code for "UC BROWSER".

 
Can anyone please help me to escape from above issue.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.column1 {
  width: 48%;
  width: -webkit-calc(50% - 20px);
  width: -moz-calc(50% - 20px);
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
}
```

Comment: Actually the right column(column2) should be 100px then remaining part of the space should occupy left column(column1).

Answer (score 0):

```
.trythis{
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% / 3 - 16px);
}
```

you can use this.

this is sample only.

Comment: thanks for ur response.. but UC browser is not identifying this code "width: calc(100% / 3 - 16px);"  so is there any specific code for mobile browsers like "-webkit-calc(50% - 20px)"

Comment: did you try this ?
/* Firefox */
width: -moz-calc(100% - 500px);
/* WebKit */
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 500px);
/* Opera */
width: -o-calc(100% - 500px);
/* Standard */
width: calc(100% - 500px);
/* IE-OLD */
width: expression(100% - 500px);
width: 98%;               /* fallback for browsers without support for calc() */
width: calc(100% - 1em);